# Is it possible to create XML file from list with another lists and dicts automatically?

Tags: python, xml

I have some list with another lists and dicts, for ex.

```py
data = [
        {"id": 0,
        "name": "Room #0",
        "students": [
            {
                "id": 345,
                "name": "William Perez"
            },
            {
                "id": 976,
                "name": "Daniel Smith"
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
```

`json.dumps()` can automatically parse it and create .json file. XML and JSON have different grammar but may be there is a way to parse this list and automatically build XML tree? Or I must build it manually?

Comment: Yup. there is an entire built-in package for XML https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, but since there's no single way to map things to attributes vs. subelements, you'd have to figure that out yourself... or just make everything elements and hope for the best, like below.

I added an affordance for setting the XML tag of a dict with `_tag`.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et


def emit_xml(tree, obj, tag="object"):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for ent in obj:
            emit_xml(tree, ent, tag)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        obj = obj.copy()
        tag = obj.pop("_tag", tag)
        tree = et.SubElement(tree, tag)
        for key, value in obj.items():
            emit_xml(tree, value, tag=key)
    else:
        et.SubElement(tree, tag).text = str(obj)


data = [
    {
        "_tag": "room",
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Room #0",
        "students": [
            {"id": 345, "name": "William Perez"},
            {"id": 976, "name": "Daniel Smith"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "_tag": "room",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Room #1",
        "students": [
            {"id": 357357, "name": "Wirelliam Pez"},
            {"id": 7222, "name": "Del Smitanih"},
        ],
    },
]

root = et.Element("root")
emit_xml(root, data)
print(et.tostring(root, encoding="unicode"))
```

outputs

```xml
<root>
  <room>
    <id>0</id>
    <name>Room #0</name>
    <students>
      <id>345</id>
      <name>William Perez</name>
    </students>
    <students>
      <id>976</id>
      <name>Daniel Smith</name>
    </students>
  </room>
  <room>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Room #1</name>
    <students>
      <id>357357</id>
      <name>Wirelliam Pez</name>
    </students>
    <students>
      <id>7222</id>
      <name>Del Smitanih</name>
    </students>
  </room>
</root>
```